# Integral of $e^{(a+ib)x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Given the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that $f(x)=e^{(a+ib)x}$, how can I compute $f'(x)$ and $\int f(x)dx$ ?
Certanly, one can use the identity $e^{ibx}=\cos(bx)+i\sin(bx)$ and then compute the derivative and integral using the well known rules from real analysis. But is it true that $f'(x)=(a+ib)e^{(a+ib)x}$ (I've shown this but I want to be sure) and is there a similar rule for computing the integral?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the derivative (suitably interpreted) of $e^{ax}$ is $ae^{ax}$ even if $a$ happens to be complex. This fact is also enough to compute an antiderivative.